# testing concept of first project

Tags: asp.net, testing, web-applications

i am currently doing my functional specification document for my project. the only thing still missing is a testing concept. my project is all about an web app with which i can record and manage employee attendance in my ojt company. i am doing the app in asp.net web forms with c# as programming language. the ide i am using is vs for web 2012.

now i need to write a testing concept. i have already read a little literature about system and module tests. i have designed my app with a few model classes whose only methods are get() and set() methods. it may be that i will write a FEW methods where parameters are expected, for how much that matters.

i am little unsure about what tests i will be planning. could you maybe help me out here? a few crude examples would also be very helpful...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here if u know about testing then there is no required of Test case & Test Plan.Its for only reference for Ur client.
 First of all
U just do Functional testing, it will help to status of your project.
If every function is work properly then application will have no major problem.
Then just go through regression & Smoke testing

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing following based on your requirements:

- Unit Testing
- Integration Testing
- Regression Testing
- Functional Testing
- End to End Testing
- Load Testing
- Stress Testing
- Performance Testing
- Beta Testing
- Security Testing
- Usability Testing

Comment: well load, stress and performance tests are no issue, i think. my web app is very small and it will never transfer big chunks of data. i think functional testing will be quite sufficient as this is for a state exam and the hours i can spend on the project are limited to 70. could you pls give an example of a function test case for asp.net web app?

Comment: If you are writing a service which exposes an api, look at SoapUI which gives you lot of ways to test SOAP, REST etc apis. Functional tests will depend on your functionalities or functional spec. If you want to test user interface, then you can use tools like selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Functional testing has many examples. 
Like Login ,Add,Edit,Delete etc
Here u Just check these are functions working properly or not.
This is the basic thing in your Application

Comment: ok lets say i am testing whether adding a user works correctly. then lets say that a user has a datafield in the database which is dateofbirth. please correct me if i am wrong here but i would now test something like add a user whose dateofbirth lies in the future, which is basically impossible. would this be a valid test case?

Comment: yup..its valid test case..Here we will also do negative testing.